# How to efficiently randomize multiple array elements between indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, concatenation

I have an array of objects that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaVcy.png

Each entry is an object within that array. What I need to do is randomize the order of each element that is NOT a headline. Each headline must remain at the initial index, but the elements between two headlines must be randomized. In the attached picture is a depiction of how it should look like.

The only difference between a headline and a regular element is that its value is a regex that looks like this #H#[0-9]+

So, what I did was:
I iterate through the array, noting the indexes of each headline.

Then, iterate through the indexes array and split the array into multiple, smaller arrays (one group for every headline).

Then, iterate yet AGAIN through the array that contains the split arrays, splice each array starting at index 0 (remove the headline element), shuffle these values, unshift the array and add the headline element at the beginning.

Finally, concatenate all the arrays in splittedArrayOfArrays into the array that I need, which is current.choices.

Performing three iterations doesn't seem very wise in performance, is there any other possible way of randomizing only groups of elements from an array?

Here's the code I hacked together to make it work:

```
                    var headlineIndexes = [];
                    var splittedArrayOfArrays = [];
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < current.choices.length; ii++) {
                        if (regex.test(current.choices[ii].value)) {
                            headlineIndexes.push(ii);
                        }
                    }
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < headlineIndexes.length; ii++) {
                        //if there is another headlineIndex, split Array until that index
                        if (headlineIndexes[ii + 1]) {
                            splittedArrayOfArrays[ii] = current.choices.slice(headlineIndexes[ii], headlineIndexes[ii + 1])
                        }
                        //if not, split until end of array
                        else {
                            splittedArrayOfArrays[ii] = current.choices.slice(headlineIndexes[ii]);
                        }
                    }
                    current.choices = [];
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < splittedArrayOfArrays.length; ii++) {
                        //remove first element and store in firstElem
                        var firstElem = splittedArrayOfArrays[ii].splice(0, 1);
                        //call shuffle with remaining elements, which shuffles the elements WITHOUT the headline
                        shuffle(splittedArrayOfArrays[ii]);
                        // re-add the headline as first elem of splittedArray
                        splittedArrayOfArrays[ii].unshift(firstElem[0]);
                    }
                    current.choices = splittedArrayOfArrays.reduce( function(prev, next) {
                        return prev.concat(next) ;
                    });
```

EDIT: I realized there was no reason to iterate over the splittedArrayOfArrays, everything could have been done from the second for loop. I think this is efficient enough for a maximum of 40ish elements that I'd have in the array anyway. Here's the final code:

```
var headlineIndexes = [];
                    var splittedArrayOfArrays = [];
                    //save indexes at which we have headlines
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < current.choices.length; ii++) {
                        if (regex.test(current.choices[ii].value)) {
                            headlineIndexes.push(ii);
                        }
                    }
                    //split choices array into groups for each headline.
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < headlineIndexes.length; ii++) {
                        //if we have another headline, make new array with elements from current index to next index
                        if (headlineIndexes[ii + 1]) {
                            splittedArrayOfArrays[ii] = current.choices.slice(headlineIndexes[ii], headlineIndexes[ii + 1])
                        }
                        //else, new array from current index to end of choices array
                        else {
                            splittedArrayOfArrays[ii] = current.choices.slice(headlineIndexes[ii]);
                        }

                        //remove first element which is the headline, store in firstElem
                        var firstElem = splittedArrayOfArrays[ii].splice(0, 1);
                        //shuffle the choices of the group
                        shuffle(splittedArrayOfArrays[ii]);
                        //add the first element back to the first position of the group
                        splittedArrayOfArrays[ii].unshift(firstElem[0]);
                    }

                    //delete choices array
                    current.choices = [];
                    //concatenate group arrays into the choices array
                    current.choices = splittedArrayOfArrays.reduce( function(prev, next) {
                        return prev.concat(next) ;
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there was no reason to iterate over the splittedArrayOfArrays, everything could have been done from the second for loop. I think this is efficient enough for a maximum of 40ish elements that I'd have in the array anyway. Here's the final code:

```
                    var headlineIndexes = [];
                    var splittedArrayOfArrays = [];
                    //save indexes at which we have headlines
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < current.choices.length; ii++) {
                        if (regex.test(current.choices[ii].value)) {
                            headlineIndexes.push(ii);
                        }
                    }
                    //split choices array into groups for each headline.
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < headlineIndexes.length; ii++) {
                        //if we have another headline, make new array with elements from current index to next index
                        if (headlineIndexes[ii + 1]) {
                            splittedArrayOfArrays[ii] = current.choices.slice(headlineIndexes[ii], headlineIndexes[ii + 1])
                        }
                        //else, new array from current index to end of choices array
                        else {
                            splittedArrayOfArrays[ii] = current.choices.slice(headlineIndexes[ii]);
                        }

                        //remove first element which is the headline, store in firstElem
                        var firstElem = splittedArrayOfArrays[ii].splice(0, 1);
                        //shuffle the choices of the group
                        shuffle(splittedArrayOfArrays[ii]);
                        //add the first element back to the first position of the group
                        splittedArrayOfArrays[ii].unshift(firstElem[0]);
                    }

                    //delete choices array
                    current.choices = [];
                    //concatenate group arrays into the choices array
                    current.choices = splittedArrayOfArrays.reduce( function(prev, next) {
                        return prev.concat(next) ;
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Performing three iterations doesn't seem very wise in performance [...]

I wouldn't worry about that. Unless there are thousands of headlines to group and hundreds of thousands of elements to shuffle, this routine won't impact performance at all.

If you really want to tweak it, you could shuffle in place, meaning inside the original array, to avoid having to copy the arrays and putting them together again.

Comment: Yes, but if I shuffle the original array I lose the groups within the array. I need the headline indexes to not change, and only shuffle the elements within groups (hence the splitting the arrays, shuffling and then putting them together).

Comment: You would only shuffle within a certain range of the array, in between two headlines. You still had to determine the positions of the headlines beforehand of course. Then, instead of shuffling the array from index 0 to the end, you would start from index right after a headline up until before the next headline, until you shuffled all the ranges.